# adding NSArray property to subclassed PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have two subclassed PFObjects as follows:

```
@interface BQQuestion : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) NSString *user;
@property (retain) NSString *questionText;
@property (retain) NSArray *answers; //this is intended to hold an array of BQAnswers 

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@end


@interface BQAnswer : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) NSString *user;
@property (retain) BQQuestion *question;
@property (retain) NSString *answerText;
@property int votes;

+(NSString *)parseClassName;

@end
```

I'm trying to add BQAnswers to a BQQuestion's answers property using the following code:

```
    BQQuestion *t = [BQQuestion object];
    t.questionText = @"Another test";
    BQAnswer *one = [BQAnswer object];
    one.answerText = @"Very nice.";
    BQAnswer *two = [BQAnswer object];
    two.answerText = @"Good.";

    t.answers = @[one, two];

    [t saveInBackground];
```

t, one, and two are all saved into the Parse cloud, but no column is being generated for BQQuestion.answers, so that association isn't saving. What am I getting wrong here?

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to an array of PFObjects is a PFRelation.  To do this you would create a column in the Question object that contains a relation pointing to Answer objects.  I assume that your class in parse is called "Question" and the added column containing the relation pointing to answers is called "answers"

```
BQQuestion *question = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Question"];
PFRelation *answers = [t relationForKey:@"answers"];
for (PFObject *answer in answers) {
  [question add:answer];
}
[question saveInBackground];
```

To retrieve the Answer objects:

```
BQQuestion *question = //assume you have the question object;
PFRelation *answers = [question relationForKey:@"answers"];
PFQuery *query = [answers query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // results contains all the answers to that question
}];
```